# JQuery Mobile - Use checkbox in split button list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use a checkbox in a split button list instead of the gear icon?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/lists/lists-split.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an html checkbox, naugtur's answer is correct. Otherwise if you want to use a checkbox *icon* on the split list to the right, just add `data-icon="check"` to the second "a" tag in the li.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use **data-split-icon="check"** in the ul tag.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="check">
```

Answer (score 0):

It sure is, but you might need to do some javascript coding for that.

If I were you, I'd try and use a count bubble and place a checkbox in it.

OR

Simply put a checkbox in the `li` element and style it to `float:right`